# Using a dictionary to correct spelling

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to write a function that takes a string argument and returns a string with the corrected spelling according to this dictionary:

For example:

```
"I ate teh whole thing lol"
```

comes out to be:

```
'I ate the whole thing haha'
```

I've done this so far but am lost on what to do:

```
def respell(string):
    respellings = {
        "teh":"the",
        "relevent":"relevant",
        "lite": "light",
        "lol":"haha" }
    respellingslist = reslepllings.split()
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Something like this... >>> respell("I ate teh whole thing lol")  comes out to be: ’I ate the whole thing haha ’

Comment: Could the downvoters at least explain their downvotes? Everybody got downvoted without explanation (except the one I personally downvoted)... That's not really constructive

Comment: I would like to know the reason why my post is down-voted ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :)

```
def respelling(string):
    respellings = {
        "teh": "the",
        "relevent": "relevant",
        "lite": "light",
        "lol": "haha" }

    res = string.split()
    for i in xrange(len(res)):
        if res[i] in respellings:
            res[i] = respellings[res[i]]
    return ' '.join(res)
```

[EDIT] one-liner:

```
return ' '.join(map(lambda s: respellings.get(s, s), string.split()))
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that the `respellings` contains a lot of possible mistyped words as keys:

```
def respell(s):
    respellings = {
        "teh":"the",
        "relevent":"relevant",
        "lite": "light",
        "lol":"haha" }
    if s in respellings:
        return respellings[s]
```

If it does not contain the required key it will do nothing.

Comment: This just returns the value for the `s` key in the `respellings` dictionary... Why not just write `respellings[s]` instead of calling `respell(s)`?

Comment: @Rightleg The answer is based on what has already been done by the author of the question.

Comment: But I think what OP wants is to correct all the words misspelled in the sentence `s`, not to get the correct spelling for the word `s`.

Comment: @Rightleg According to the OP, my answer does exactly what he or she asks. The comments with further explanations appeared later, Mr. Downvoter. Start being constructive from yourself first.

Comment: Wow. Sorry to have hurt your sensibility. You'll have to explain to me where I have not being constructive, though, because I think I explained my point of view rather clearly. You should not take downvotes that personally... I wanted to give your point back but I can't... Well, sorry.

Answer (score -1):

The following function takes a string and corrects all the misspellings specified in the `respellings` dictionary passed as an argument:

```
def respell(s, respellings):
    for wrong in respellings:
        try:
            index = s.index(wrong)
            s = s[:index] + respellings[wrong] + s[len(wrong)+index:]
        except:
            print(wrong + " not in string")
    return s


>>> print(respell("I aet teh wohle tingh",
                 {"aet":"ate", "teh":"the", "wohle":"whole", "tingh":"thing"}))
"I ate the whole thing"
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to only use a dictionary to correct spelling and all wrong spellings are present as key then your code should be as follows

```
def respell(word):
   respellings = {
      "teh":"the",
      "relevent":"relevant",
      "lite": "light",
      "lol":"haha" }
   try:
       return respellings[word]
   except KeyError:
       return word

string = "I ate teh whole thing lol"
correct_string = " ".join(respell(word) for word in string.split())
```

and in-case if you want to do a proper spell check which would be slightly expensive is as follows.

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

def similar(a, b):
    return SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio()

def respell(word):
    known_words = set(["the","man","relevant","light","haha"])
    if word in known_words:
         return word,1
    max_similarity = 0
    correct_word = None
    for known_word in known_words:
        similarity_value = similar(known_word, word)
        if max_similarity<similarity_value:
             similarity_value = max_similarity
             correct_word = known_word
    return correct_word,max_similarity
```

The above function returns two value a word and a similarity value which is between 0 and 1. zero (0) if no words are even near similar and 1 if given word is known or correct word.